# Using header names as a filter parameter in a dashboard

Tags: filter, parameters, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I have a data table that resembles the structure here:

```
| Prof | PI     | Class |
|:----:|:------:|:-----:|
| Dr.K | Louisa |  A    |
| Dr.L | Jenny  |  B    |
| Dr.X | Liu    |  C    |
```

Filter 1: I'd like to create two dropdown, single selection parameter-filters, the first of which contains the headers of the columns. So, filter one would contain the option to select: Pro, PI, or Class.

Filter 2: The second filter would then dynamically change to represent values of the selected column. If a user chose "Prof" in Filter 1, Filter 2 would show: Dr. K, Dr. L, and Dr. X. The table in the dashboard would then reflect the chosen filters.

I believe choosing "only relevant values" on Filter 2 would take care of some of the issues, but I still don't understand how I can turn column headers into a list, and those values still retain the integrity of the original columns. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

IF [Parameter 1] = STR("Prof") THEN [Prof] ELSEIF [Parameter 1] STR("PI") THEN [PI] END

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).